# Custom domain Heroku trouble

Tags: web, heroku, dns, subdomain, custom-domain

I have set up a custom domain with Heroku as websitename.com. The problem is I still can only connect to the app from websitename.herokuapp.com and when I click on websitename.com  it says there is "nothing here click on the app to build something amazing" even when I follow the link from the custom domain page settings.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set from your domain host "forward domain".

Comment: thank you I think that may work but then when people are on my website will it  show up  wont it still show up as website.herokuapp.com?

Comment: It will show website.herokuapp.com only after they searched website.xyz, so yes they will still see website.herokuapp.com if you use the forward method.

Comment: How do I get it so it doesnt do that

Comment: You have to set up your DNS, try doing what they say https://help.heroku.com/MTG1BIA7/how-do-i-connect-a-domain-to-my-heroku-app

Comment: Thank you foru your input i appreciate you taking the time out to link that

Comment: Happy new year!

Comment: Did you do it?I just did mine.

Comment: Thank you Yes I did I just re did it and it worked thanks happy new years to you too.